# Container for multiple ::math::linearalgebra::mkMatrices in TCL

Tags: tcl

I would like to divied a bigger `::math::linearalgebra::mkMatrix` to multiple smaller ones and store them in a list or any other container. Unfortunatly I did not manage to find a way to do this with lists. Is it possible to store multiple `::math::linearalgebra::mkMatrices` in a list, array or even in a dictionary.

I tried to store the names in a list and then whenever I needed the `mkMtarix` I used `[lindex matrices 0]`. However this didn't work.

Is there any good material around about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the commands in the `math::linearalgebra` expect to take the name of a variable holding the matrix. That means that while their value can go nicely in a list for storage, you can't really manipulate them like that. *You're much better off using a Tcl array for what you're doing.* Then you can go:

```
# An all-zero 3x3 matrix
set collection(0) [math::linearalgebra::mkMatrix 3 3 0.0]

# Turn it into an identity matrix; notice the use of a variable to name the element
set matrixID 0
for {set i 0} {$i < 3} {incr i} {
    math::linearalgebra::setelem collection($matrixID) $i $i 1.0
}
```

The only things to be careful of are that elements of a Tcl array are *not* ordered, but in compensation you can use non-trivial keys into the array as well as simple integers. This means you can use composite keys like `1,2` (or `fred,wilma`), which you can generate like `$x,$y`, i.e., as in:

```
set matrixX 1
set matrixY 2
for {set i 0} {$i < 3} {incr i} {
    math::linearalgebra::setelem collection($matrixX,$matrixY) $i $i 1.0
}
```

A powerful technique that you might find very useful.

Comment: Thanks, this worked very well. Arrays are the way forward in my case!